# Click between messages on Chrome console (error vs warning etc)

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I saw in a fellow developer's Chrome Tools that he has this sidebar where can click easily between errors and warnings in the console. However, mine does not have this and the console input simply plans across the whole width of the developer tools. How can I add this sidebar on the console so I can click between message types? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To toggle the console sidebar use button next to the 'Clear console' button.

[Position of console sidebar toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9V5h.png)